# ORA-01841:(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Tags: sql, oracle

I do have this value SQL Query. But facing the error (as the title).

```
BETWEEN TO_DATE('20190401', 'yyyymmdd') AND TO_DATE('20190501', 'yyyymmdd')
```

ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Comment: can you post the full sql? There is nothing wrong with this fragment - `select * from dual where sysdate BETWEEN TO_DATE('20190401', 'yyyymmdd') AND TO_DATE('20190501', 'yyyymmdd')` works just fine (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0e0aa18378cedc6b6d399a39c900e3e5 - see no error). The error is elsewhere in your sql

Comment: share full condition and what is the data type of comparison column

Comment: the 20190401/20190501 is coming as TEXT/String.

Comment: @JeannellCasaje convert your string column date type then do comparison

Comment: What data type is the column you are trying to compare?